# Identify records diagonally and generate primary key

Tags: postgresql

I need to check the data diagonally and generate respective primary key for the same.

[image]

In the table ID1, ID2, Place and Date are the columns.

I need to check the data diagonally with respect to Date, for eq:

Row2 : ID1 - 36495037 and Date - 01-06-2019  : Identifier should be 54321 and version should be 1
Row4 : ID2 - 36495037 and Date - 01-06-2019  : Identifier should be 54321 and version should be 1
Row6 : ID2 - 36495039 and Date - 01-06-2019  : Identifier should be 54321 and version should be 1

ID1 in row2 = ID2 in row4 and ID1 in row4 = ID2 in row6 : Identifier - 54321  and version 1,2 and 3 respectively.

I have tried using below query, joins and union as well, but it's not helping.

```
select ctid,ID1,ID2,Place, Date ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by ID1,ID2, Date ORDER BY ctid)  as trans_version from table_name;
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Sample data are helpful, but some abstract description of the process is necessary. "Diagonal" does not explain it sufficiently.

Comment: Please check row2's ID1 and Date with row4's ID2 and Date. Both are same. So i need to generate same identifier with version 1 and 2

Comment: Maybe it would help to show the result you want. I can tell you want to compare ID1 with ID2 in other rows where the dates match. When one of the rows match what should the output be? Also, row 3 should match row 5 as well right? When you say "generate same identifier with version 1 and 2" I don't understand because the rows with that identifier already have version 1 in one row and 2 in the other.

Comment: Identifier and Version is the result i need